# How to Convert multiple arrays of objects to single object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have arrays like below:

```js
[{"1":"test1"},{"2":"test2"},{"3":"test3"}]
```

I want to convert it like below:

```js
[{"1":"test1","2":"test2","3":"test3"}]
```

I want result as a single object.please provide solution for this.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: yes, i have done it using loop. but i want easiest way

Comment: then you better show your efforts next time

Answer (score 9):

One quick way is to use `Object.assign` and `spread operator`

```js
let arr = [{"1":"test1"},{"2":"test2"},{"3":"test3"}]
let obj = Object.assign({},...arr);

console.log(obj);
```

Doc: [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: And if an array is desired, i.e. `["test1", "test2", "test3"]`, use `Object.assign([], ...arr);`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [{"1":"test1"},{"2":"test2"},{"3":"test3"}];
var newarr = arr.reduce(function(data,val){
  Object.assign(data[0],val);
  return data;
},[{}]);
console.log(newarr);
```